# Initializing a static templated member of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

I have the following code snippet, but it does not work. the dataMap member is supposed to contain a callback function that takes a T& and the T to pass to the callback at the appropriate time. The template member initialization fails (with g++ 4.7.2) with: `error: need ‘typename’ before ‘MyClass<T>::DataMap’ because ‘MyClass<T>’ is a dependent scope`. I tried sticking typename in where it says, but then got a different error: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token`.
Is it possible to do it this way, or do I need to remove the typedefs from the initialization? I tried going down that path, but it got illegible quickly and spit out even more errors.

```
template <typename T> class MyClass
{
public:
  typedef void(*CallbackType)(T&);
  typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<T, CallbackType>/**/> DataMap;
  static DataMap dataMap;
  ...
};

template <typename T> MyClass<T>::DataMap MyClass<T>::dataMap = MyClass<T>::DataMap;
```

Comment: Did you try putting 'typename' in before both occurances of MyClass<T>DataMap?

Comment: I tried both of these:
`template <typename T> typename MyClass<T>::DataMap MyClass<T>::dataMap = MyClass<T>::DataMap;` and
`template <typename T> typename MyClass<T>::DataMap MyClass<T>::dataMap = typename MyClass<T>::DataMap;`
Both failed.

Comment: @kwiqsilver: The first typename is necessary, the second is not; but you need to use the parentheses (`()`) after `DataMap` if you use copy-initialization. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is correctly suggesting you that you might want to include the `typename` keyword, because `DataMap` is a qualified *dependent* name in `MyClass<T>::DataMap`. The static member definition should look like this:

```
template <typename T>
typename MyClass<T>::DataMap MyClass<T>::dataMap;
```

The member will be default constructed, so there is **no need to copy-initialize it**. Thus, it is enough to omit the `= MyClass<T>::DataMap` part (which gives you troubles because you forgot the parentheses after `DataMap` on the right side of the copy-initialization):

```
// This is also valid (mind the parentheses to invoke the
// constructor of `DataMap`), but unnecessary.
template <typename T>
typename MyClass<T>::DataMap MyClass<T>::dataMap = MyClass<T>::DataMap();
```

Comment: Do you not need 'typename' after the = sign?

Comment: @bstamour: You can use it, but it is not required.

Comment: Similar to how it's not required in an inheritance list I assume. In that context it can only be a type and thus there's no ambiguity.